# How do I access “Shared with me” on Google drive with VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-drive-api

im completely new to programming and im trying to open a file from the Shared with me folder on Google drive, but it’s not showing on the mini window. those that show are the ones on my drive. How can I open a file that’s shared with me?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use the [web version](https://drive.google.com/drive/shared-with-me) of Google Drive for this.

1. Click on the shared item you want to add to your drive
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>
   [image: shift Z]
3. Add the item to wherever you want. Google Drive on your desktop should now begin syncing the shared item.